# Erlang ets remove / filter element

Tags: erlang, fold, ets

I use elang ets table as a simple cache. I want to use a process to scan the table and remove expired elements (multiple).

with    ets:foldl

```
expire_table_example() ->
Tab = ets:new(ets_tab, [named_table, set]),
ets:insert(Tab, [{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5},{f,7}]),
Tab1 = ets:foldl(fun({Key, Val}, Acc) ->
if
   (Val > 3) -> [{Key, Val} | Acc];
   true -> Acc
 end
end, Tab, Tab),
io:format("end ~p ~n", [Tab1]).
```

I got

```
[{f,7},{e,5},{d,4}|ets_tab] %% the ets_tab is NOT expected.
```

How Can I fix This?

Any other API's would do this better?

Comment: The reason you're getting the atom `ets_tab` in your list is that you're putting it there by using `Tab` as the second argument to `ets:foldl/3`, which is the initial value of the fold accumulator. You should be using `[]` for the initial value instead.

Comment: Actually, I want to return  an empty ets table there.  if I use [], it could be an empty list. right?

Comment: If you want to empty the whole table, just use [`ets:delete_all_objects/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#delete_all_objects-1).

Comment: @SteveVinoski.  Thanks. it make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use ets table as accumulator.

For your purpose you can use [ets:select_delete/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#select_delete-2):

```
1> Tab = ets:new(ets_tab, [named_table, set]).
ets_tab
2> ets:insert(Tab, [{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5},{f,7}]).
true
3> ets:select_delete(Tab, [{{'$1','$2'},[{'=<','$2',3}],[true]}]).
3
4> ets:tab2list(Tab).
[{f,7},{e,5},{d,4}]
```

Or you can use [ets:tab2list/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#tab2list-1) to get list of all values, filter them and after that re-insert to table:

```
1> Tab = ets:new(ets_tab, [named_table, set]).
ets_tab
2> ets:insert(Tab, [{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5},{f,7}]).
true
3> L = ets:tab2list(Tab).
[{f,7},{e,5},{d,4},{c,3},{b,2},{a,1}]
4> L2 = lists:filter(fun({Key,Val}) -> Val > 3 end, L).
[{f,7},{e,5},{d,4}]
5> ets:delete_all_objects(Tab).
true
6> ets:insert(Tab, L2).
true
7> ets:tab2list(Tab).
[{f,7},{e,5},{d,4}]
```

Comment: An easier way to write the `select_delete` call for this case is to use [`ets:fun2ms/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#fun2ms-1): `ets:select_delete(Tab, ets:fun2ms(fun({_,V}) -> V < 3 end)).`

Comment: Thanks.  will use ets:select_delete/2

Comment: If you will use fun2ms don't forget to add "-include_lib("stdlib/include/ms_transform.hrl")." in your erl file.

Comment: BTW, your second example doesn't work. You should delete objects instead of inserting them or delete whole table first.

Comment: Yes, I really forgot 'delete_all_objects' step. Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way it can be done is by using  [list comprehensions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html).

```
1> Tab = ets:new(ets_tab, [named_table, set]).
ets_tab   
2> ets:insert(Tab, [{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5},{f,7}]).    
true    
3> [{X,Y} || {X,Y} <- ets:tab2list(Tab), Y>3].    
[{f,7},{e,5},{d,4}]
```

Comment: Thanks.  this will need re-insert after the filter.

Comment: Ah sorry I hadn't realised you wanted both lists kept, in that case you can assign Tab1 = [{X,Y} || {X,Y} <- ets:tab2list(Tab), Y>3]. and that way you will have both Tab and Tab1 for use.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that deleting huge numbers of objects periodically may result
in undesirable latency spikes.
There is interesting project which have cache segments as separate ets tables
and deletes outdated objects by dropping whole ets, maybe you will find it interesting as well

https://github.com/fogfish/cache

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But with this cache,  How can I extend the TTL for cached object?